# Gradle unable to download dependencies

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I can't seem to be able to connect gradle to the internet. This is the [terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDIRh.jpg). I've tried it on multiple devices using intellij and visual studio code, to no avail.

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software, firewall or proxy?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)